# Slider range values moving along with Angularjs only

Tags: angularjs, slider

I have a slider range, and I would like the value to follow the slider without using jQuery, but only angularjs. I didn't see anything on Internet concerning this issue, is that impossible?

Thanks for answering.

Here is the code of my slider :

```
<input  type="range" min="10" max="1000" ng-init="slider = 10" ng-model="slider" ng-change="adaptNumberSlider()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular-slider: Slider directive implementation for AngularJS, without jQuery dependencies

http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/